# Load large image from Flutter Image Picker plugin?

Tags: flutter, image, max, size, picker

I want to limit the image size by 1920x1080 for loading large images using `Image_Picker`. If I don't specify the max size, I get the image size as 4000x3000. If I specify the max size as 1920x1080. I get the image size as 1440x1080. Does the `Image_picker` crop or resize the image to fit in max size? It looks like that it does a resize but it doesn't keep the ratio. Does anyone can explain how `Image_Picker` works when it selects image larger than the max size specified?

Comment: Have you tried using AspectRatio as parent of image widget yet? 
Or you can use this package to resize one dimension but still maintains aspect ratio of image.
https://pub.dev/packages/image

Comment: No, I don't want to introduce another package to resize the image. The Image_Picker should handle it properly. If not, I'll just use ImageProvider to resize the image manually. I just don't understand what's the maxWidth is used in Image_Picker.  You can certainly load image with width larger than maxWidth.